# VS 2010 "Go to Top of Page" Shortcut

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I looked around and googled but did not find any "Go to Top of Page" Shortcut on VS 2010.
This is very frustrating when your class is 2000 lines long and you want to scroll to top.
Anyone ?

Comment: Why can't you use Control Home on keyboard ?

Comment: Btw: your code class should normally not contain 2000 lines of code, if so then its time for you to refactor your code. a normal max should be a 1000 lines of code

Comment: @JohnnBlade Number of lines ain't good at measuring quality of code, might be relevant in case of methods but not for the class on the whole

Answer (score 14):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd>, it's a convention in windows application (works with any text editor: Word, Notepad, etc.)

Comment: I learn a new SO editor tag `<kbd>`... why I can't find it on the editor?

Comment: Actually, this an standard HTML tag + a custom CSS. A [discussion has exists related to extending the SO editor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36785/could-the-kbd-tag-be-added-to-the-stackoverflow-editing-help).

Comment: Aha ! Bazinga ! [Ctrl] + [PAGE UP] Sounded so much more intuitive and convenient... :-) This seems easy but it is seriously frustrating when you do not know it

Answer (score 5):

Not sure how to do it with any mouse shortcut.

But, with **keyboard** you can do it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd>

By the way - with **mouse**, in case you want to reach to the top of the defined `Class` in `filename.cs` file, you can goto `left top combobox` in your class file and `select the class name` and it will take you to top of that selected class name as in below screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Home
It's like any other windows doc